# How do i search for a particular value from an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an array of objects called 'Tags' of type :

```
type Tag = {
   id: number,
   label: string
}
```

Below is some sample data inside it.

```
const [tags, setTags] = useState<Tag[]>([{id: 1, label: "random"}, {id: 2, label: "important"}, {id: 3, label: "ignore"}])
```

I have an input field which takes input and sets it to "input" state ***on change***.

I want to display a paragraph element only if the searched input field doesn't exist inside the tags.

I was unable to find a way to directly search it as the tags array is made of objects and i want to search that object's label property.

So i ended up doing something like this...

```
{tags.map(tag => {
     if(!(tag.label.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase()))){
         return <p>{input}</p>
  }                   
})}
```

but this would render the paragraph each time the input doesn't match the values. So in this case it renders the paragraph 3 times if i add a new label. I want it to render just once. How do i fix this?

Comment: do you want to render the paragraph when label contains input? you are doing the opposite because of using `!`

Comment: No, if the label doesn't match with the input then only i want it to render and i want it to render just once.

Comment: Understood, check my answer. You can use array.prototype.some or every.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `filter` to filter tags and then if result has a length > 0 show `<p>{input}</p>` one time:

```
return (
   {tags.filter(tag => !(tag.label.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())).length > 0 && 

         <p>{input}</p>
            
})});
```

Answer (score 0):

To render the `input` in a `p` tag when none of the labels includes it:

```
const Bla = () => { // assuming Bla is your component
  const shouldRenderInput = tags.every(
    (tag) => !tag.label.toLowerCase().includes(input.toLowerCase())
  );

  return <>{shouldRenderInput && <p>{input}</p>}</>;
};
```

see [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)